# How to add a default parameter value in the #selector

Tags: ios, swift, function, addtarget

I have a function:

```
func handleChange(isShown:Bool){
        if isShown {
           // do something A
        }else{
           // do something B
        }
    }
```

If I want a UISlider to add the above action with the **isShown** defaulting to ***false***, and I will call the method `handleChange(isShown:Bool)` with **true** in another function.
The wrong code as follows:

```
slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleValue(isShown:false)), for: .valueChanged)
```

And I know the right code needs to be:

```
slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleValue(isShown:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

I just want to know how can I set the 'isShown' as false in swift? Appreciate you can reply.

Comment: You can't. Either there is no parameter or the parameter must be the `UISlider` instance. The syntax with parameter must be `handleChange(_ sender: UISlider)`

Comment: You can't. All you can pass is the `sender`, which in this case is a `UISlider`. Your "right code" isn't.

Comment: See my edited first comment.

Comment: @vadian,@dfd,@Jaydeep  thanks, and I will go to have a further understanding of 'addTarget'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use a helper function that is separate from the `selector` function. The selector function can call the helper function, which can have as many parameters as you wish.

Adding the target:

```
slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleChange(_ sender: UISlider)), for: .valueChanged)
```

Target function:

```
func handleChange(sender: UISlider) {
    // logic based on the action or slider
    doSomething(isShown: true)
}
```

Helper function:

```
func doSomething(isShown: Bool) {
    // make your changes using the parameters here
}
```

Comment: thanks for your replying